# C# Selenium - one ChromeDriver for multiple forms?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a few forms and I'd like to have them operating on one WebDriver. Is it somehow possible? I tried creating the driver in a new class but I couldnt pass it to the forms.

Code in the form:

```
selenium1 sel = new selenium1();
sel.create();
ChromeDriver driver = sel.get();
```

Class code:

```
namespace Vulcan2
{
    public class selenium1
    {
        ChromeDriver driverx;
        public void create()
        {
            ChromeDriver driverx = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        public ChromeDriver driver()
        {
            return driverx;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be helpful to share the code you have so far, even if it's not working to give more context to your issue.

Comment: Thanks, Edited my post.

Comment: Show me how do you do this for one driver and single form

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your Driver Class as a static class:

```
static public class selenium1
{
    static ChromeDriver driverx;

    static public void create()
    {
        driverx = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    static public ChromeDriver driver()
    {
        return driverx;
    }
}
```

And you may call like this:

```
selenium1.driver().Close();
```